# XSLT Textoutput

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document, something like this:

```
<project>
    <name>Project 1</name>
    <value>1</value>
    ...
</project>
<project>
    ...
</project>
```

I want to convert this to a .csv file, which some people at work can edit in Excel. I want the result to be able to be pasted as a config-file. So I want a .csv like this:

```
"<add project=""",PROJECT_NAME_FROM_XML,""" value=""",VALUE_FROM_XML,""" />"
```

Is this possible with XSLT?
The main problem is those `<` and `>`
I can only print them out as `&gt;` or `&lt;`
But then I need to do a find-replace in Excel.

If this can't be done, I can always create a html-result, and copy/paste it from the browser I guess.

Comment: To generate CSV, you should use `xsl:output method="text"`.

Comment: Excel can read XML files directly: https://trumpexcel.com/convert-xml-to-excel/

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, but does that decode `&gt;` in the output?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky That might be a better solution. I have to dive into the Transform posibilities I guess. Since I need some custom columns, and might need to save the transform rules because this will be done on a regular basis.

Comment: If the XSLT processor is in charge of serializing the result then, with `xsl:output method="text"`, it will certainly not output `<` in text as `&lt;`, but simply as plain `<`. The same for any other escapes that are only used for XML or HTML output method.

Comment: @MartinHonnen No, but how can I use a `<` within my XSLT?

Like:
    <xsl:template match="project">
        <xsl:text><</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
        <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

This is invalid xslt because of the single `<` and `>`

Edit: ow wow... just realised you can't format in comments :)